# How to get B2C id_token inside ClaimsTransformation.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, httpcontext

Is it possible to get the id_token returned by B2C after authentication inside of ClaimsTransformation.cs class?

I have tried to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into the class, but it gets stuck in an infinite loop, calling the same method again and again, resulting in Stack Overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following  to the Azure AD OpenID Connect technical profile:

```html
<ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateOtherMailsFromEmail" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Reference Link : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml